# Is this a scala bug or am I doing something wrong

Tags: scala

I have some code that works in scala 2.10 but fails with an 'Assertion Error' in scala 2.11. I would like some feedback on whether I am being an idiot, if something has changed, or if there is a bug in 2.11 (unlikely, I know.)

Its a simple thing. I have a file of words that is read in and the letters split out into a map.

```
for (token <- logData.getLines().flatMap(x => x.split("\\s+"))) {
        // Ignore empty lines which appear in the word count as ""
        if (token != "") {
            words += 1
            counts(token) += 1
            for (letters <- token.split("")) {
                if (isOrdinary(letters)) {
                    letterCounts(letters) += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Having read in and mapped the letters to letterCounts, I'd now like to extract the letter with the maximum frequency. I try to do this with

```
val maxLetterCounts = fixedLetterCounts.values.max
    val highestLetter = letterCounts.filter((t) => t._2 == maxLetterCounts)
```

and I get the error when it tries to run the filter.
This works in scala 2.10 but in scala 2.11 I get

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: List(value _2$mcI$sp, value _2$mcI$sp)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.suchThat(Symbols.scala:1916)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.matchingSymbolInPrefix$1(SpecializeTypes.scala:1460)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transformSelect$1(SpecializeTypes.scala:1483)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transform1(SpecializeTypes.scala:1579)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2$$anonfun$transform$3.apply(SpecializeTypes.scala:1428)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2$$anonfun$transform$3.apply(SpecializeTypes.scala:1428)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.reportError(SpecializeTypes.scala:1420)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transform(SpecializeTypes.scala:1428)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transform(SpecializeTypes.scala:1371)
at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1347)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transform1(SpecializeTypes.scala:1712)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2$$anonfun$transform$3.apply(SpecializeTypes.scala:1428)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2$$anonfun$transform$3.apply(SpecializeTypes.scala:1428)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.reportError(SpecializeTypes.scala:1420)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transform(SpecializeTypes.scala:1428)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transformSelect$1(SpecializeTypes.scala:1467)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transform1(SpecializeTypes.scala:1579)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2$$anonfun$transform$3.apply(SpecializeTypes.scala:1428)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2$$anonfun$transform$3.apply(SpecializeTypes.scala:1428)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.reportError(SpecializeTypes.scala:1420)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transform(SpecializeTypes.scala:1428)
at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anon$2.transform(SpecializeTypes.scala:1371)
at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1347)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
```

I've truncated the error somewhat.

Any idea why this works and returns me the map I want in 2.10 but breaks in 2.11?

Thanks

Dean

P.S. I'm sure the style of this is not in the scala spirit and if there are better ways to do anything I show, feedback is great, but please answer the main question too.

Comment: Can you point the exact line where the error is? Also, can you add the assertion that fails?

Comment: This looks kind of familiar but I don't remember details. Can you provide a complete working example and specify your 2.11 version?

Comment: I added an edit to show where it failed. It fails when the filter tries to run. I don't know what you mean by 'the assertion that fails'. The error message follows the filter line immediately with no other information.

Comment: Travis, I'll cut something together and get a complete version up tomorrow. It's version 2.11.5 that is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's scala bug indeed - [SI-9099](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9099)

> Fix Version/s: Scala 2.11.6